# Replacing HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert with redis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stackexchange.redis, httpruntime.cache

I have some inherited code still running on .net framework 4.7.2 its a webapi. This runs in aws in windows containers.  The calls to it are resource intensive and thus there is quite a bit of caching the caching its using HttpRuntime.Cache.

Issue we have at the moment is that the caching is per instance ideally it should be using a distributed cache like redis.  In the calls to HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert we have:

```
public async Task<T> CacheAndGet<T>(string key, Func<Task<T>> cacheFunction, Func<CacheDependency> cacheDependency) where T : class
{
    var result = Get<T>(key);
    if (result == null)
    {
        Log.Warning("cache is empty for for {cacheKey}", key);

        result = await cacheFunction();
        Put(key, result, cacheDependency());
    }

    return result;
}

private static void Put<T>(string key, T value, CacheDependency cacheDependency)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, default(T))) return;

    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, value, cacheDependency);
}
```

The thing I am struggling with is how to replicate the cacheDependancy part with redis.  Is it possible to replicate dependancy based caching with redis?  I did read something about tagging with redis sets?  Is this the way to go? Anyone done anything like this before?